# Facebook Graph API latests comments (in feed)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I know there are new comments in feed. Do I have to iterated through all objects in my feed? it sounds expensive.

In other words, I need to find out if there are any new comments on my wall since certain timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't seemed to be solvable. The work around it to use FB webhook.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/v2.5